# JavaScript for select/Textbox action

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have found MANY MANY examples of what Im trying to do. Unfortunately, I cant get any to work :)

I need a text box to change to the value of the selected dropdown.

I have created a fiddle.

The JS i am trying to use is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#goal option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() == $("#reason").val();
}).attr('selected', true);

$("#goal").live("change", function() {

    $("#reason").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/phpman13/q8h5kupj/

I tried using FireBug and it reports that .live is not valid.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

.live() is deprecated, **use .on() instead**. It follows the same syntax.

From: https://api.jquery.com/live/

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear on your exact requirement. I understood that you want update the text based on selected drop-down item. If it is the requirement.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reason").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
});
$("#goal").change(function() {
        $("#reason").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`try`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("#goal option").filter(function() {
          return $(this).val() == $("#reason").val();
       }).attr('selected', true);

    $("#goal").on("change", function() {

    $("#reason").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("#goal option").filter(function() {
          return $(this).val() == $("#reason").val();
       }).attr('selected', true);

    $("#goal").on("change", function() {

    $("#reason").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
});
});
```

Comment: Ozil answer give you the value attribute, mine give you the inner text (human content)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you All. changing the

```
.live
```

to

```
.do
```

Worked.